# Can I use an activerecord relation to find nested attributes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Sorry if my question is poorly worded. I'm struggling to express it well. Lets try it in code!

I have a client model that has_many projects. If I have an ActiveRecord relation generated like so;

```
clients = Client.where(':sign_up_time < ?', Time.now)
```

and I want to get a list of all of the projects belonging to the clients returned in this relation, how would I go about it? I can do it in Ruby easily enough and get an array of projects returned, e.g.

```
projects = clients.inject([]) {|proj,cli| proj << cli.projects}.flatten
```

which is absolutely fine, but I thought there might be a nice clean way of doing this in ActiveRecord.

The important thing is that I want to use the `clients` object as my starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really ActiveRecord, but doing the following is somewhat of an idiom for doing this:

```
projects = Client.where(':sign_up_time < ?', Time.now).map(&:projects).flatten
```

this is pretty much the same as what you have, but much more cleanly written. You could also do something this, though:

```
clients = Client.where(':sign_up_time < ?', Time.now)
projects = Project.where(:client_id => clients)
```

This results in `projects` being an `ActiveRecord::Relation` rather than an array, which can be more useful. It's also a more SQL-oriented approach, which can be faster.

Comment: That's cleaner Ruby at least, and I do like getting an ActiveRecord::Relation out of the second version. I think that's what I'm after. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you want is a join, read all about it:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

```
Project.joins(:clients).where(:clients=>'sign_up_time < ?', Time.now)
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work I think, but it doesn't let me use my existing clients object.